# Probabilities and propositional logic

Tags: probability, logic, probability-distributions, propositional-calculus

I have to show the following

1. Is Pr $[\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi]=1,$  so is $\operatorname{Pr}[\varphi]=\operatorname{Pr}[\psi]$
2. Is $\operatorname{Pr}[\varphi \rightarrow \psi]=1,$ so is  $\operatorname{Pr}[\varphi] \leq \operatorname{Pr}[\psi] $
3. For all  $\varepsilon>0$  $\operatorname{Pr}[\varphi \rightarrow \psi] \geq 1-\varepsilon,$ implies that $\operatorname{Pr}[\varphi] \leq \operatorname{Pr}[\psi]+\varepsilon .$
4. In none of the cases holds the reversal . (For the third case Fall this means, that there is a distribution, formulas and an  $\varepsilon>0$ exists with $\operatorname{Pr}[\varphi] \leqq \operatorname{Pr}[\psi]+\varepsilon$ but $\operatorname{Pr}[\varphi \rightarrow \psi]<1-\varepsilon $

Could someone please help me through that?

Edit1:

For the second one i did the following

$P[\varphi \rightarrow \psi]=1 \equiv P[\neg \varphi \vee \psi] = 1$

$ \equiv P[\neg \varphi] + P[\psi] - P[\neg \varphi \wedge \psi]=1$

$\equiv 1-P[\varphi] + P[\psi] - P[\neg \varphi \wedge \psi] = 1$

$\equiv P[\psi] - P[\neg \varphi \wedge \psi] = P[\varphi]$

$\implies P[\varphi] \leq P[\psi]$

Now i am stuck with the first case
wherer i have
$$P[\varphi \rightarrow \psi] \geq 1- \epsilon \equiv P[\neg \varphi \vee \psi] \geq 1 - \epsilon$$
$$\equiv P[\neg \varphi]+P[\psi]-P[\neg \varphi \wedge \psi] \geq 1- \epsilon $$
$$\equiv 1-P[\varphi]+P[\psi]-P[\neg \varphi \wedge \psi] \geq 1 - \epsilon $$
$$\equiv P[\psi]-P[\neg \varphi \wedge \psi] \geq - \epsilon + P[\varphi]$$
$$\equiv P[\psi] + \epsilon \geq P[\varphi] + P[\neg \varphi \wedge \psi]$$

Comment: Anyone some advice on 4. ?

Answer (score 1):

**Notice:** If $p\geq q+r$ and $r\geq 0$, then $p\geq q$.

You have reached $\Pr[\psi]+\epsilon\geq\Pr[\varphi]+\Pr[\neg\varphi\wedge\psi]$, and so ...

Comment: Well yeah that simply states that Pr[ψ]+ϵ≥Pr[φ] thanks any ideas for the 4 ?

Comment: i have now done 1 to 3 i know that for the fourth i have to show that these do not hold backwards for each